# Clicking on submit button need to close the modal window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Once i click on submit button page is getting refreshed the modal window is not getting closed.Need to close the window once i click on submit button.Here is the code i have tried.

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <form class="modal-content" action="contactus.php" method="post"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container">       
     <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" required>
  <label for="companyname"><b>Company Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name" name="companyname" id="companyname" required>  
  <label for="phonenumber"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" required>       
  <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>
  <label for="countries"><b>Country</b></label>
  <script src="js/countries.js"></script>
  <select id="country2" name ="country2" ></select>   
  <div class="clearfix">
    <button id="submit_contact" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>

  </div>
</div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Contactus:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit_contact'])) {
   if(!$mail->send()) {
     $msg = "Error while sending email";
     $msgclass = 'bg-danger';    
   } else {
     $msg = 'A mail with recovery instruction has sent to your email.';
     $msgclass = 'bg-success';  
  }
} ?>
```

Comment: use ajax to submit your form and close model on request complete

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha tried in this format by adding the same contact us page but still it is refreshibng

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha  this is the fiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/wsqfpv4m/

Comment: this one works https://jsfiddle.net/zumwtjLk/1/ issue was you have used `#submit_contact` button selecter for on submit function .but you should use form selecter .i have moved id to form and now it's working fine

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha  you have used #contact but in the form you didnt use

Comment: i modified your fiddler so yes #contact model is missing .but what i;m trying to say is page is not reloading after you submit the form.can you clarify more what you need exactly

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha once i submit the form the page should not get refreshed

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zumwtjLk/1/  this isn't refresing

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha its still refreshing the page